# How to call external PHP file in AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have code to check username and password in test.php file.

But when I am calling this ajax it is always showing alert of wrong username and password.
Can anyone tell where I am going wrong?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'http://externalurl/external/test.php',
    contentType: "text/html",
    data: 'uname=' + uname + '&pass=' + pass,
    success: function (data) {
        if (data == 'success') {
            alert('success');
        } else {
            alert('Wrong user name and password.Please try again');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: "where I am going wrong?" => you're sending a password with GET.

Comment: check the net console in Firebug or Chrome's dev tool and see what's the actual response. Also, what James said

Comment: And you are not using an object for `data` which will cause problems  on certain characters. Use `data: {uname: uname, pass: pass}` instead!

Comment: [Call external url through $.ajax in wordpres theme](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544522/call-external-url-through-ajax-in-wordpres-theme)

[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629254/how-to-get-data-from-external-url-in-jquery)

Comment: @ThiefMaster : I used this `data: {uname: uname, pass: pass}` but still same problem

Comment: Can we have test.php's code please?

Comment: test.php : `if($_GET['uname']=='admin' && $_GET['pass']=='admin'){
 echo 'success';
}
else{
 echo 'no';
}
exit;`

Comment: Your Answer is here: http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy and/or here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: @Kunal  call `alert(data);`  in  the success() function. Tell the output

Comment: @ngen : It showing blank

Comment: You php is not responding with correct output so how will the javascript work then!.

Comment: I read same origin policy after that I come to know Javascript doesnt support cross domain request

Comment: use `data: {uname: "admin", pass: "admin"}`  instead of data=....

Comment: then tell me what's `alert(data);` showing.

Comment: @Kunal  You can get JSON data returned from an external domain.  Other than that, you cant get data from an external server. Check my answer.

Comment: could you provide a test address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'test.php',
dataType: 'jsonp',
    contentType: "text/html",
    crossDomain:'true',
    data: {uname: "admin", pass: "admin"},
    success: function (json) {
        //process the json here.
    }
});
```

You are using incorrect format for `data` field of ajax .

And no, Javascript doesn't normally allow you to access data via ajax from external servers.It will give out

> Origin http://*externalhost* is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

**Edit:**

However, You can set `crossDomain`  and `dataType:'jsonp'` for getting JSON data from an external server.

Comment: now it showing response in firebugs net window but not alerting it

Comment: do `alert(data);`   .  ie, `success: function (json) { alert(json) }`

Comment: @Kunal !! what do you mean by  you already did. What's it alerting?. It wont alert anything unless you return  JSON data from the PHP .

Comment: means I already tried this code : `alert(data); . ie, success: function (json) { alert(json) }` but still alert not showing the response is coming into the firebugs net window i.e. yes and no

Comment: that is because Javascript doesnt allow you to access NON JSON data from external server. Aren't you reading at all?. Respond from the server with JSON.